# PHP try-catch some problems

Tags: php, try-catch

Hello. Is it possible to use such code in **PHP**?

```
try {
  throw new InternalException('Internal');
} catch (InternalException $e) {
  throw new Exception('Internal To global');
} catch (Exception $e){
  print $e->getMessage();
}

class InternalException extends Exception {
  // some code here
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What is THE problem you're after?

Comment: Yes. But maybe try it will be much more quicker than ask question here.

Comment: you can extend the exception class what  is the error or problem you are facing

Comment: Why do you want it this way? -> [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Sometimes I have a Server errors and I need to write in a log file, after writing is done , I want to execute an throw to Global Exception which set and show for user a simple user message, but not Technical message. and another problem is that I like the look, But not so much try-catch multiple levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest multiple `try...catch` instead.

```
try {
    throw new InternalException('Internal');
} catch (InternalException $e) {
    try {
        throw new Exception('Internal To global');
    } catch (Exception $e){
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
}

class InternalException extends Exception {
  // some code here
}
```

See [PHP: Exceptions - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense to "transform" Exceptions. Don't throw em if you won't handle them.

You can catch different Exceptions this way:

```
try {
    throw new InternalException();
} catch (HardwareException $e) {
} catch (InternalException $e) {
    // this catch block will be executed
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // all other exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can catch specific exceptions separately.

Comment: I want to use this structure of code

try {
  throw new InternalException('Internal');
} catch (InternalException $e) {
  throw new Exception('Internal To global');
} catch (Exception $e){
  print $e->getMessage();
}

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are only caught if they're thrown in `try` blocks. Exceptions thrown in `catch` blocks are *not* caught within other sibling `catch` blocks of the same `try..catch` statement. You have to nest the whole thing in another outer `try..catch` block to catch those.